# Prompting for Credentials for CreateFile

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I would like to design a function that checks a file for some text.  It takes a file path, and this path can be a UNC path such as \path\to\file\share.

It will use the current users credentials as well. What I want to do is have the ability to prompt the user for new credentials to use; In pseudocode

```
hCreds = NULL;
if (!fAutoLogon) { hCreds = PromptForCredentials(); }

hFile = CreateFile( pszFile, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ ,
                    NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL , hCreds);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`CredUIPromptForCredentials()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375177.aspx) or [`CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375178.aspx) to get the user's credentials, then use [`LogonUser()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184.aspx) and [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612.aspx) to impersonate that user, then call `CreateFile()` with your UNC path, and then finally call [`RevertToSelf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379317(v=vs.85).aspx) to stop impersonating after you close the file.

Comment: I had to use LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS and LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 for LogonUser to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to a network share using [WNetAddConnection3()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
    NETRESOURCE nr;

    nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY;
    nr.lpLocalName = NULL;
    nr.lpRemoteName = dcpath;
    nr.lpProvider = NULL;

    dw = WNetAddConnection3(NULL, &nr, NULL, NULL, CONNECT_INTERACTIVE | CONNECT_PROMPT);
```

This will prompt for credentials.  I believe the path string must point to a directory rather than to a file; usually it will just be `\\server\share`.

If the connection is successful, you can then use CreateFile() to open the file.  The MPR will automatically use the existing connection.

You should use [WNetCancelConnection()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to disconnect from the server once you are finished using the file.

One potential advantage of this approach over Remy's is that it works even if your credentials on the server are different to those on the local machine.